# How to access the result of an SQL SUM function in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

The following SQL query in Postgres yields an accurate calculation:

```sql
select sum(invoice_items.unit_price * discounts.percentage/100) as discount from invoice_items join items on items.id = invoice_items.item_id join merchants on merchants.id = items.merchant_id join discounts on discounts.merchant_id = merchants.id where invoice_items.quantity >= discounts.threshold and invoice_items.invoice_id = 513;
```

The ActiveRecord equivalent is producing successful SQL statement:

```rb
invoice_items.select('sum(invoice_items.unit_price * discounts.percentage/100)')
    .joins(:discounts)
    .where('invoice_items.quantity >= discounts.threshold')
```

And the AR is returning an `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`...yet I cannot get the AR to output the actual SUM.

The question:
How can the AR expression be updated to return the actual value of the SUM function?

What I've tried:

1. Aliasing the SUM function and then calling it on the resulting `AssocationRelation`
2. Iterating through the `AssociationRelation` to call the alias (method doesn't exist)
3. Removing the SUM function, adding the alias an then iterating over the results, but I need to return the sum....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe asked this question prematurely.... I've solved the issue.

I update the ActiveRecord query to be this:

```rb
invoice_items.select('invoice_items.unit_price * discounts.percentage/100 as calculated_discount')
    .joins(:discounts)
    .where('invoice_items.quantity >= discounts.threshold')
```

then in the view I simply called

```rb
@invoice.discount.sum(&:calculated_discount)
```

Comment: Leaving the question up and not selecting my answer in case someone else has a better solution